# JSON - Replace $scope object in external JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to get data from an external JSON file in my application. Most of my data loads in a DataTables table but my JSON data includes $scope, which I don't think is working since it's external. The data for status and errorCode are already in the same JSON file. What can I replace `$scope.status[i]` and `$scope.errorCode[i]` with to get the rest of the data to load?

Part of my JSON code:

```
"status" : [
{"id": 1, "name": "Active"},
{"id": 2, "name": "Inactive"},
{"id": 3, "name": "Unknown"}
],

"errorCode" : [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Code01"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Code02"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Code03"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Code04"}
    ],

"apps" : [
    {"appName": "App01",
        "dateCreated": "01/01/2015",
        "dateUpdated": "01/04/2015",
        "payload": "Payload01",
        "status": "$scope.status[0]",
        "errorCode": "$scope.errorCode[0]",
        "errorDesc": "Desc01",
        "recordCount": 1,
        "recordFail": 1},
    {"appName": "App01",
        "dateCreated": "01/02/2015",
        "dateUpdated": "01/05/2015",
        "payload": "Payload02",
        "status": "$scope.status[0]",
        "errorCode": "$scope.errorCode[1]",
        "errorDesc": "Desc02",
        "recordCount": 1,
        "recordFail": 2},
    {"appName": "App03",
        "dateCreated": "01/03/2015",
        "dateUpdated": "01/06/2015",
        "payload": "Payload03",
        "status": "$scope.status[1]",
        "errorCode": "$scope.errorCode[2]",
        "errorDesc": "Desc03",
        "recordCount": 2,
        "recordFail": 1}
```

HTML code that is calling the JSON data:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(i, th) in head" value="{{th.id}}" class="{{th.class}}"><span>{{th.name}}</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:search" ng-click="clickRow(app)" ng-class="{selected: app === selectedRow}">
            <td>{{app.appName}}</td>
            <td>{{app.dateCreated}}</td>
            <td>{{app.dateUpdated}}</td>
            <td>{{app.payload}}</td>
            <td>{{app.status.name}}</td>
            <td>{{app.errorCode.name}}</td>
            <td>{{app.errorDesc}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(i, th) in head" value="{{th.id}}"><span>{{th.name}}</span></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And:

```
<table class="table display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(i, th) in details" value="{{th.id}}"
                class="{{th.class}}"><span>{{th.name}}</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{selectedRow.appName}}</td>
            <td>{{selectedRow.errorDesc}}</td>
            <td>{{selectedRow.recordCount}}</td>
            <td>{{selectedRow.recordFail}}</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Surely you mean `if (head in data)`? `for(x in data)` is going to loop through all the keys in data.

Comment: The `for` loop works, I'm concerned about the JSON data that includes `$scope`

Comment: I'm assuming the intent is that those properties in your JSON are intended to be expressions that you want to parse on the client?

Comment: @Claies yes, in 2 tables. I have added part of the HTML code that does that. I am using AngularJS. The expressions and JSON data work so far, except for the columns that have `$scope`

Comment: Clearly my attempted answer wasn't quite on mark.  Honestly, I'm not really sure that what you are trying to do can be accomplished.  what you are trying to do is store the names of variables as data, but JavaScript really isn't designed to function in that way. Ultimately it would have to be evaluated twice, once to figure out the variable to use, then again to figure out the value that variable is currently holding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my JSON data to call the index of `status` and `errorCode` instead of calling the scope:

```
"status": 0,
"errorCode": 0,
```

I also changed my HTML to reflect the changes so my data would appear in the table:

```
<td>{{status[app.status].name}}</td>
<td>{{errorCode[app.errorCode].name}}</td>
```